# Use regex pattern as argument to function

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, functions

I want to be able to pass a plain regular expression like so

```
autocmd BufReadPost * call TextEnableCodeSnip('bash', /^hello/, /^world/, 'SpecialComment')
```

To a function and use it within as a regular expression without having to convert to a string and back. I want it to have the effect of:

```
vimfunction! TextEnableCodeSnip(filetype,start,end,textSnipHl) abort
  " ...
  execute 'syntax region textSnip'.ft.'
  \ matchgroup='.a:textSnipHl.'
  \ keepend
  \ start=/^hello/ end=/^world/
  \ contains=@'.group
endfunction
```

Which modifying the function like so works fine.

I was hoping that changing the line to look like:

```
  \ start=start end=end
```

and just using the variables directly as the data type they were passed as would suffice. Unfortunately, this fails with the error:

```
E15: Invalid expression: "/^hello/, /^world/, 'SpecialComment')"
```

Which leads me to believe vim doesn't support this. Does it in another way? Or do I have to use an intermediary string?

I am new to Vimscript and couldn't find anyone else trying to do the same.

Comment: You need to pass to the function a valid script object (i.e.: number, string, list, dictionary). 'Regular Expression' is not a valid script object. I would use a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a string for that:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * call TextEnableCodeSnip('bash', '^hello', '^world", 'SpecialComment')

function! TextEnableCodeSnip(filetype,start,end,textSnipHl) abort
  " ...
  execute 'syntax region textSnip'.g:ft
  \ 'matchgroup='.a:textSnipHl
  \ 'keepend'
  \ 'start=/'.a:start.'/' 'end=/'.a:end.'/'
  \ 'contains=@'.g:group
endfunction
```

Remark: the code seems to assume a 'ft' and 'group' global variables to exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply! This is pretty much where I started but I needed to have clarified that there wasn't a way to pass regex directly and you gave me that clarification.

Only reason it matters is because my pattern has quotes in it, so I get to deal with escaping those plus a bunch of double-escaping any regex characters (like `\s` -> `\\s`, for instance) when using `"` strings. My pattern uses both single and double quotes so it'll be fun to escape no matter what. I was hoping there was a way to make the patterns more readable without escaping them, but looks like I'm out of luck